# Controller 'ngModel', required by directive '...', can't be found

Tags: angularjs, directive

What's going on here?

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('submitRequired', function (objSvc) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

          // do something
        }
    };
});
```

Here is an example of the directive in use:

```
<input submit-required="true"></input>
```

Here is the actual error text:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'submitRequired', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=submitRequired
    at http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at getControllers (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:5972:19)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:6139:35)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:5550:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:6132:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:5550:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:5458:30)
    at http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:1299:27
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:11634:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://www.domain.ca/Scripts/angular/angular.js:11734:23) <input submit-required="true"> angular.js:9159
(anonymous function) angular.js:9159
$get angular.js:6751
nodeLinkFn angular.js:6141
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5550
nodeLinkFn angular.js:6132
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5550
publicLinkFn angular.js:5458
(anonymous function) angular.js:1299
$get.Scope.$eval angular.js:11634
$get.Scope.$apply angular.js:11734
(anonymous function) angular.js:1297
invoke angular.js:3633
doBootstrap angular.js:1295
bootstrap angular.js:1309
angularInit angular.js:1258
(anonymous function) angular.js:20210
trigger angular.js:2315
(anonymous function) angular.js:2579
forEach angular.js:300
eventHandler angular.js:2578ar.js:7874
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controller 'ngModel', required by directive '…', can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807929/controller-ngmodel-required-by-directive-cant-be-found)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

As described here: [Angular NgModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController), you should provide the `<input` with the required controller `ngModel`

```
<input submit-required="true" ng-model="user.Name"></input>
```

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate that! I will mark this as answer. I have a follow up question. Should I post another question or change my original?

Comment: Here is the follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807929/controller-ngmodel-required-by-directive-cant-be-found

Comment: i had mistakenly typed `ng-models` and got this error.

Comment: @Radim Kohler  I'm happy that your response actually helped someone in need,i myself am close to achieving this. From the above input statement , for the "ng-model" attribute can i use string concatenation like "{{ RootObjectName+"."+ ModelName }}" ??!! As my models in the $scope are not straightforward and are dynamically created in the controller based on input from DB

Comment: @pavankumar check this link http://next.plnkr.co/edit/iLP1QZjMJ7EkLlCF?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1 this `ng-model="RootObject[alias]"` will work if session will have `  $scope.RootObject = {};  $scope.alias = "FirstName"` ... instaead of alias, even **forEach** could provide the dynamic name

Comment: @Radim Köhler thanks for the quick response Radim,let me just check it out

Comment: @Radim Köhler i think in the plnkr the value in the scope variable is passed,what i want is to pass the model to the directive to be bound to a input element in the directive,is there a way i could do that??

Comment: @pavankumar, look, I tried to quickly help... but it seems you need more attention. Please, create new question, ask here... you will get your answer... comments are .. not the right place, I'd say.. good luck ;)

Comment: @Radim Köhler i actualy did, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966080/angular-6-custom-directive-with-ng-model

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution to this issue is `ng-model` attribute is required to use that directive.

Hence adding in the 'ng-model' attribute can resolve the issue.

```
<input submit-required="true" ng-model="user.Name"></input>
```

Comment: This solved mine. Thanks. I think we have missed the point that to trigger ng-change, there should be a ng-model bind to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the line

```
  require: 'ngModel',
```

if you don't need `ngModel` in this directive.  Removing `ngModel` will allow you to make a directive without that`ngModel` error.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is also caused by having ng-value instead of ng-model

Error:

```
<input ng-value="item.name" ng-change="nameChanged()">
```

Works:

```
<input ng-model="item.name" ng-change="nameChanged()">
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same error, in my case I miss-spelled ng-model directive something like "ng-moel"

Wrong one:
 **ng-moel="user.name"**

Right one: 
**ng-model="user.name"**

[image]