# Why can't I modify the isolated scope value in my directive controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Given the following Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YicBDARAf5umI0PdCL8L?p=preview

Why isn't $scope.someVal being set in the directive controller?

I would expect the output of the template to show

```
someVal = ABC controllerVal=DEF
```

but instead it shows

```
someVal = 123 controllerVal=DEF
```

Html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <my-test some-val="123"></my-test>

    <script>
      angular.module("myApp", [])
      .directive("myTest", function() {
        return {
          restrict: "E",
          scope: {
            someVal: "@"
          },
          template: "someVal = {{someVal}}  controllerVal={{controllerVal}}",
          controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.someVal = "ABC";
            $scope.controllerVal = "DEF";
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the usual issue of passing reference vs valueType. Use `Model.someVal` ... check it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21882900/1679310. *(Model will be passed as a reference so the value changed in the inner scope of directive will be changing the field `Model.someVal` of that reference - therefore all will work as expected)*

Comment: Also for two way binding we need `=` instead of `@`. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21807951/1679310). If we want to let the change made in directive to go to caller, we need a reference to be passed as also already [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21882900/1679310)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/zCSWDa?p=preview You dont need 2 way binding.. Only thing you need to make sure is that your scope update runs later, otherwise it will get overridden by one-time bound value.

Comment: @PSL: Copy as answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Comment: @Scottie Sure il add it with explanation. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't get the updated `scope.someVal` (done from directive controller), which is a one way bound value (`@`), is because when the directive compiles it overwrites the scope.someVal with the interpolated value from one time binding (Basically it runs interpolation on `attr.someVal` while creating the isolated scope). So ultimately you will see the one time bound value. One workaround would be to delay your overwrite by making the call async so that it gets updated during the next digest cycle.

Example:- Wrap it in a $timeout or use push it to async queue

```
    controller: function($scope, $timeout) {

         $scope.$evalAsync(init);//Set up initialization

         $scope.controllerVal = "DEF";

         function init(){
            $scope.someVal = "ABC";
          }
      }
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4md6xJ?p=preview)**