# Gulp Compiling Angularjs 1 Scripts in, incorrect order

Tags: angularjs, gulp

Why does this happen? When I compile the scripts using `GULP` the console will display errors, explaining that my `directives` and/or my `controllers` are not registered. Then to correct this error I create the app variable within the `controller` file and it then renders a new error, then I put the app variable declaration back and everything works fine.

**This is my Gulp Script**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*'],
    replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});

var path = {
    jsFiles: "./js/**",
    scriptFile: "scripts.min.js",
    output: "dist/assets/"
};

var options = {
    ie8: true,
    warnings: true,
    mangle: true
};

gulp.task('scripts', function (cb) {

    return gulp.src(path.jsFiles)
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plugins.jsdoc3(cb))
        .pipe(plugins.concat(path.scriptFile))
        .pipe(plugins.babel())
        .pipe(plugins.ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(plugins.uglify(options))
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write("../../maps"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.output))
})
```

**TLDR:** MY Gulp task sometimes compiles the `AngularJS` `directives` and `controllers` out of order rendering my app declaration `undefined`.

Comment: Because ./js/** does not guaranty build order. Where does angular.min.js placed?

Comment: it'd be placed in js/ folder at the root. Inside js I have: /js /js/directives /js/data/

Comment: If I am not mistaken gulp.src takes also array. Try to pass array with path to angular.min.js as first element. Btw, it is good to separate third-party code from your own. It will helps if you using watch mode.

Comment: Oh this is my tasks/scripts.js file. I parsed out each task into their own seperate js file. And okay I'll give that a shot thanks. :) I'm currently trying build order and it seems to have fixed some errors.

Comment: I ended up going your route, but I additionally didn't have a model for one of my data points so my directives were not being registered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807834/controller-ngmodel-required-by-directive-cant-be-found

Comment: Go ahead and answer the question so I can assign this problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass globe to the

```
gulp.src
```

No ordered is guaranteed, so it is possible to get wrong order time to time. But gulp.src also accepts array of the pathes you need to include and this should guarantee the order

So, try to split your bundle and pass path to the angular.min.js as a first element like this:

```
gulp.src(['path/to/angular.min.js', 'path/to/your/code'])
```

Comment: I ended up grouping each of the file types, directives, services, controllers, etc. Into their own seperate folders then passing them in by file type. Thanks bud!

Comment: No problemo :), glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You should sort angular files, and there are some libs that does that.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort is one of them.